# how to render image based on mobile height and width?

Tags: php

In WAP application, i have to render image based on height and width of
    mobile in php.if user download image then the image should be fit on his mobile.
    please give me sample example on above scenario.

Comment: This is more of a CSS/JS question.  If you don't want to send excess data to the user you COULD load images in AJAX and resize them using PHP, but this would cause a ton of load on your server.  Take a peak at some responsive design articles and threads, I think you'll find exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do it using PHP,**

server-side languages process all their actions before the requested file gets downloaded by the end user therefore no information about the users PC will be received (apart from the IP address of course).

**There are only two ways you can perform such an action**,

**the first** is using JavaScript (bad idea for the many who have scripting disabled) or

**Second** through CSS3 media queries (not supported in IE). If you want something cross browser that does the job and will work for everyone, you're out of luck. The fact of the matter is, your design should be naturally flexible, not dependant on certain widths anyway.

```
 // Create a WURFL Manager and detect device first
 $wurflManagerFactory = new WURFL_WURFLManagerFactory($wurflConfig);
 $wurflManager = $wurflManagerFactory->create();
 $device = $wurflManager->getDeviceForHttpRequest($_SERVER);

 // Example 1: Get display resolution from device
 $width = $device->getCapability('resolution_width');
 $height = $device->getCapability('resolution_height');
 echo "Resolution: $width x $height <br/>";

 // Example 2: Get the WURFL ID of the device
 $wurflID = $device->id;
```

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: sorry that i did not cleared you how i am getting width and height of mobile device.actually with the help of wurfl i am getting user handset information.if i have height and width of device then how can i render image for that will fit on user device.

Comment: `...therefore no information about the users PC will be received (apart from the IP address of course).` I'm pretty sure the server has more information than that. What about `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`?